# column filling in R

Tags: r, rstudio

Hi i'm working on a logistic regression exercise, i have a database with n rows and 4 columns one of them is a theoretical probability, my aim is to compare these theoretical probabilities with a certain value that i defined if the probability is less my predicted probability is 0 else it's 1 so what i figured out that my data is a list of four lists, therefore i created another blank list that i would fill with the predicted probabilities however i seem to have a algorithmic problem in the loops that i tried to write can you help me ?

```
    library(readxl)
d<-read_excel("/home/ali/Downloads/roc.xlsx")
typeof(d)
#classification table

#le seuil que j'ai choisi de prendre 
seuil <- 0.095
pred <- c()
for(i in d$Proba_theo){
  for(j in pred){
    if(i<seuil){
       j = 0
       pred[j]=j
    }
    else{
       j = 1
       pred[j]=j
  }
}
}
pred
```

Comment: Why are you looping over pred? pred is empty.

Comment: I don't know how to fill my pred column that's why i looped over pred

Comment: And changing the value of `j` in the middle of the `j`-loop is probably not a great idea!

Comment: All you need is `pred <- as.numeric(d$Proba_theo >= seuil)` - there is no need for a loop as R is a vectorised language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
seuil <- 0.095
pred <- rep(NA,nrow(d))
for(i in 1:nrow(d)){
  if(d$Proba_theo[i]<seuil) {
    pred[i]=0
  } else {
    pred[i]=1
  }
}
pred
```

or alternatively in vectorised form

```
pred=ifelse(d$Proba_theo<seuil,0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that you are overwriting the value of the j while in the for loop.

what you could do to make your variable, you might use a mutate instead of a for cycle. I made you a small example:

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(testVar = rnorm(100))
df %>% mutate(ifelse(testVar > 0, 1, 0))
```

Hence in your case it would be something like:

```
d <- d %>% mutate(ifelse(Proba_theo >  0.095, 1, 0))
```